# Appended element does not remain in parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the [following code](https://jsfiddle.net/v7r5m74h/3/), if one input has the error icon then the error icon appended previously in the other input is removed. Why is this, and how can I resolve this?

```
<div class="reg-input">
  <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First name">
</div>
<div class="reg-input">
  <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last name">
</div>
```

```js
var $errorIcon = $('<i class="error">!</i>');
var $regInput = $('.reg-input input');
$regInput.on('focus', function() {
    var $inputWrapper = $(this).parent();
    if ($inputWrapper.has('i').length === 0) {
        $inputWrapper.append($errorIcon);
    }
});
```

```css
.error {
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    background: brown;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.reg-input {
    position: relative;
}

.reg-input input{
    width: 100%;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because the same element gets moved to other location, you need to clone before appending:

```
$inputWrapper.append($errorIcon.clone());
```

[Update Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7r5m74h/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are appending the same element it move to the new location, Move the element declaration in the `if` block create a new element and append.

```
$inputWrapper.append('<i class="error">!</i>');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9gzum893/1/)

Comment: yeah that will also work, as closure will not happen